# Image current and return current

Tags: pcb, emc

I find I'm a little confused about "image current" and "return current" in PCB/EMI/EMC design. Are they equivalent? Many docs use this model when talking return current

[image]

Exactly, I will treat the return current as a current flowing on a image plane. So, may I call it "image current"? If so, then what about this situation:

[image]

Is there image current flowing on the image plane?

Comment: Do you have a good reference for "image current"

Comment: No, I don't have such a document. But I saw some docs mentioned it.